# Loop through and extract item values from JSON notation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{"items":
 [
  {"id":"5054","nodeId":"3286"},
  {"id":"8888","nodeId":"7777"},
  {"id":"3421","nodeId":"1234"},
  {"id":"8748","nodeId":"2435"}
 ]
}
```

When I click a button on my page I want to run a script that retreives the value of a cookie which is stored as JSON notation and then loops through the items within the notation and compares the id of the button that was clicked to the ids stored in the JSON. If the id matches, nothing is done. If it does not then the new item should be added to the JSON object and saved back to the cookie so the next time the server loads the page, different content is displayed.

The addition of a new item to the existing JSON notation is the easy bit and I already have the code for that. The problem is, my code for looping through the JSON notation doesn't seem to be working:

```
var cookieTest = getCookie("wishlist"); /* JSON */

    // Check a cookie exists
    if (cookieTest != null) {

        var test = JSON.parse(cookieTest)

        for (prop in test) {
            console.log(prop);
            console.log(prop[0].id);
        }
    }
```

The first console.log seems to return items however when I try and return the id of the first item in the array, undefined is returned.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did u check the cookieTest? is it null before parsing?

Comment: cookieTest isn't null. It contains the JSON notation I have listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first drill down to "items" before you can loop through the array.

```
var cookieTest = '{"items":[{"id":"5054","nodeId":"3286"},{"id":"8888","nodeId":"7777"},{"id":"3421","nodeId":"1234"},{"id":"8748","nodeId":"2435"}]}';
// Check a cookie exists
    if (cookieTest != null) {

        var test = JSON.parse(cookieTest)
        var items = test.items ? test.items : [];
        for(thing in items) {
            var current = items[thing];
            console.log(current.id);
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6n8dr/

Comment: I thought this was probably the case. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: sweet! glad to help. please accept this as your answer if you don't have any other questions about this so it closes out the question. =)

Comment: Yeah I was going to buddy. The guy above has answered with the same but you got there first so you will get the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `for (in)` loop iterates over the property *names* of an object, not the property *values*.

```
var prop;
for (var p in test) {
  prop = test[p];
  console.log(p, prop, prop[0].id);
}
```

*PS:* Or if you just want to iterate over the property with name `items` of `test` (you already know the property name you're interested in and that the value will be an array).

```
for (var i = 0, e = test.items.length; i < e; ++i) {
  console.log(i, test.items[i], test.items[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try jQuery see if it works:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(cookieTest);
console.log(obj.items[0].id);
```

Comment: Although I am using jQuery elsewhere I don't really want to use it for this purpose as it would be overkill in this situation (the downvote was not me btw)